# Is there a way to make `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` run faster?

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

On Fedora 19, when I run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` it locks my display for about 15-20 seconds.  The command completes successfully, but I am unsure of why it takes so long.  I'm assuming there is an X module that has to be reloaded, or something like that.

Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: I assume you are using Linux?

Comment: How large is your .Xmodmap file? Can you run `time xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` and also `strace -f -tt xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`?

Comment: @terdon Yes, Linux.  Fedora 19.  Updated the post with that info.

Comment: @EtanReisner 248 lines.  I have tried `time` but it reports 0.02s.  That's what makes me think there is some part of X that is consuming most of the run-time.  `strace` reports approximately 0.02s as well.

Comment: Can you post the output from those commands? Also what do you mean exactly when you say your display locks up?

Comment: @EtanReisner By display locking up, I mean that when I run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, the display stops updating for 15-20 seconds.  After 15-20 seconds have passed, the display begins updating again.  Here is the output of strace: http://pastebin.com/J7Gxx88G

Comment: You could try attaching strace to your X process immediately before the xmodmap run and see if that finds anything. You might want to see if you can duplicate this on a secondary display, possibly even something like xephyr, to simplify the amount of stuff in the trace. Do you see anything odd in top when this happens?

Comment: Same issue here, 15 lines, runs in 2-3 seconds.